# Remove a variable part of an image URL using .htaccess

Tags: regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have an image that is accessible with the following URL:

```
https://localhost/hta/-7524-34-B.webp
```

I need to be able to access the same image with a URL like the following and remove the `<something>` part:

```
https://localhost/hta/<something>-7524-34-B.webp
```

How can I do this with `.htaccess`?

**UPDATE:**

I added the following `.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^.*?(?=&). /hta/$1 [NC,L]
```

When I write the following URL it's not opening the image. Only listing the `hta` directory.

```
http://localhost/hta/something-else&-7524-34-B.webp
```

Comment: You will have to be a bit more precise... Is it orrect that you actual file in the physical, server side file system is called `-7524-34-B.webp` and that it is located in the `DOCUMENT_ROOT` of your http host? And that the "something-else" is actually irrelevant for the request? Then the answer to your question is: "yes". And you will find lots of existing examples here on SO for the rewriting rule you need to implement for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To internally rewrite a URL of the form `/hta/<something>-7524-34-B.webp` to `/hta/-7524-34-B.webp` (removing `<something>`) you could do something like the following near the top of your root `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^hta/[^/]+(-7524-34-B\.webp)$ hta/$1 [L]
```

The regex `[^/]+` matches `<something>`, which is discarded. The remaining part of the URL-path `-7524-34-B\.webp` is captured and this is referenced in the *substitution* string (2nd argument) with the `$1` backreference.

Comment: Thank you so much! if my -7524-34B.webp image files dynamic name like another-image.webp how can I do

Comment: @OnderAkbulut Just change the `-7524-34-B\.webp` part of the regex to `another-image\.webp`. The backslash-escape is necessary before the literal dot to negate its special meaning.

Comment: ok bro but I can't do it manually this is getting from db :(